# Using expression trees to create a custom order by in linq to entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a table that's mapped, but after compile additional columns can be added or removed from the table.  I'm trying to come up with a linq query that will take those new columns into account.  In this scenario, I want to order by one of those dynamic columns.  This is what I have so far.

```
var queryableData = dc.wf_task_ext_attributes.AsQueryable();
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime), "ExtValue105");

// The next line is where it fails
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
      typeof(Queryable),
       "OrderBy",
       new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, queryableData.ElementType },
       queryableData.Expression,
       Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime, DateTime>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>
                         (orderByCallExpression);
```

It's failing with the following message:

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a property on the entity that represents the additional column?

Comment: No, the columns are added after the mapping.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work, you can dynamically build order by calls but you have to have existing properties to put in them to be valid. EF holds a mapping from property to column, but you have not property and it doesn't know about the columns.

Comment: Is queryableData of type IQ<DateTime>? Seems not to be since you are calling CreateQuery<string>.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you looked at Dynamic Linq? For things like this it's usually a lot easier than handrolling expression trees.

Comment: I have tried dynamic linq, it goes with what mant101 was saying, if it's not a property it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is `queryableData` of type `IQueryable<DateTime>`? Seems not to be since you are calling `CreateQuery<string>`.

Your call to `Expression.Call` seems to assume that this is an `IQueryable<DateTime>`. Make sure that it is.

You can find out how to correctly build a LINQ query by hard-coding the query and then decompiling the resulting assembly.

Comment: No, it should be of type `wf_task_ext_attributes` as it's a call to linq to entity.  I'm aware of the CreateQuery mistake, but I'm not concerned about that yet as the code never hits that line.  I tried setting the types in the lamba to `wf_task_ext_attributes`, but it said that it didn't match type `datetime`

Comment: Well, if the query source is of type wf_task_ext_attributes, why are you trying to treat it as DateTime? (There is no good answer - I'm trying to understand the mistake you are making).

Comment: I'm trying to sort it by a column, the column is of type datetime, not the queryable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to create something like `Queryable.OrderBy(queryableData.Expression, ExtValue105 => ExtValue105)`. I have no idea why would you expect that to work.

If I understand your question correctly, you need to dynamically create an expression like `attribute => attribute.ExtValue105` and then you can use that to call `OrderBy()`.

The code could look something like this (assuming `queryableData` is `IQueryable<Attribute>`):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attribute), "attribute");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "ExtValue105");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

IQueryable<Attribute> results =
    Queryable.OrderBy(queryableData, (dynamic)lambda);
```

You could use `queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery()` manually to avoid the `dynamic` call, but that would be more complicated.

Comment: @Smeegs I don't think so, EF somehow has to know how to translate the expression into SQL.