# Linq to Entities - Custom method (OrderBy) fails in lambda statement

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I am trying to write a custom OrderBy extension method for Linq to Entities, where I can sort ASC or DESC based on a parameter. My first attempt was the following:

```cs
public static class LinqExtensions
{   
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByExtension<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool isDescending = true)
    {
        return (isDescending) ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector) : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

This works great!... As long as I don't use this method inside a lambda statement. A toy example would be:

```cs
using (var dbContext = new FooDBEntities())
{
    var foo = dbContext.Fubars.SelectMany(x => dbContext.Fubars.OrderByExtension(y => y.Foo, true)).ToList();
}
```

When I run the above code the program blows out and I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[ExpressionTreeFoo.Fubar] OrderByExtension[Fubar,String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ExpressionTreeFoo.Fubar], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeFoo.Fubar,System.String]], Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

The error pretty much says it all. The framework does not know how to translate my custom extension method into something that SQL can understand.

I've been doing some googling but I haven't seen anything that says definitively that this is or is not possible. So my question is.. Is there any way at all to make a custom OrderBy method (extension method or not) that will work inside a lambda expression?

Comment: Are you sure it's fully working with simple queries? Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: Yes, I've verified. I'm using: context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s) to print out the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a solution by using the NuGet Package: **LinqKit.EntityFramework**

The way it works is you first call .AsExpandable() this puts a wrapper around the IQueryable. Then you have to call .Invoke on the inner lambda expression. Invoke is an extension method of LinqKit. When this query is called, LinqKit will recursively scan threw the expression tree and when it hits an expression that calls the extension Invoke it will remove the call to Invoke and re-write the expression tree in a way that the CLR engine can understand. A full description can be found at: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

```cs
static void EFTest()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DBEntities())
    {
        // debug - print query
        dbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

        // get order by expression
        var orderByExpression = GetOrderByExpression(dbContext, true);

        // execute query
        var result = dbContext.FooTables
                              .AsExpandable()
                              .SelectMany(x => orderByExpression.Invoke(x))
                              .ToList();
    }
}
```

```cs
private static Expression<Func<FooTable, IOrderedQueryable<FooTable>>> GetOrderByExpression(DBEntities dbContext, bool isDesending)
{
    if (isDesending)
    {
        return x => dbContext.FooTables.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date);
    }
    else
    {
        return x => dbContext.FooTables.OrderBy(y => y.Date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a lambda is not a compiled expression tree with a known interface with SQL directly.  A lambda in the sense that you are creating is an anonymous C# method, which is only executable by the CLR.  While they share the same syntax they are different elements of the framework.  If you would like to implement your own custom Linq-To-Entities expressions you will need to research building `Expression Trees`.

To explain it simply - How do you turn this:

```
(isDescending) ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector) : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
```

Into this?

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] ORDER BY [MyTable].[MyColumn] DESC
```

You have to properly define how to do this using Linq expression trees.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932612/using-expression-trees-to-create-a-custom-order-by-in-linq-to-entities) is a similar question to yours (but without an answer)
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) is the Microsoft documentation on expression trees

The reason it fails only when you pass it into a lambda expression is because what you are passing in is unable to be compiled into a true expression tree

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and insight into the nuances of lambda statements. I will check out the links you provided. -cheers

Comment: @Soto if this fit your needs please consider marking it as the answer

Comment: I still don't have a clear solution, short of creating my own framework to build up Expression Tress. I'm still working on it though if I come up with solution using your link, or if know on else answers with a clear solution, I'll will give you the points.